# How can I search in arrays of integers with a compound MongoDB Atlas search query?

Tags: mongodb, search, full-text-search, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I am working on a function that helps me find similar documents, sorted by score, using the full-text search feature of MongoDB Atlas.

I set my collection index as "dynamic".

I am looking for similarities in text fields, such as "name" or "description", but I also want to look in another field, "thematic", that stores integer values (ids) of thematics.

---

**Example:**

Let say that I have a reference document as follows:

```
{
 name: "test",
 description: "It's a glorious day!",
 thematic: [9, 3, 2, 33]
}
```

I want my search to match these `int` in the thematic field and include their weight in the score calculation.

For instance, if I compare my reference document with :

```
{
 name: "test2",
 description: "It's a glorious night!",
 thematic: [9, 3, 6, 22]
}
```

I want to increase the score since the thematic field shares the `9` and `3` values with the reference document.

---

**Question:**

What [search operator](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/operators/#operators-ref) should I use to achieve this? I can input array of strings as queries with a `text` operator but I don't know how to proceed with integers.

Should I go for another approach? Like splitting the array to compare into several `compound.should.term` queries?

---

**Edit**:

After a fair amount of search, I found this [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/range/#limitation) and [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/index-definitions/#limitation):

> Atlas Search cannot index numeric or date values if they are part of an array.

Before I consider to change the whole data structure of my objects, I wanted to make sure that there is no workaround.

For instance, could it be done with [custom analyzers](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/analyzers/custom/#custom-analyzers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a trigger to my collection. Each time a document is inserted or updated, I update the `thematic` and other similar fields counterparts, e.g. `_thematic`, where I store the string value of the integers. I then use this `_thematic` field for search.

Here is a sample code demonstrating it:

```
exports = function (changeEvent) {

const fullDocument = changeEvent.fullDocument;
const format = (itemSet) => {
    let rst = [];
    Object.keys(itemSet).forEach(item => rst.push(itemSet[item].toString()));
    return rst;
};
let setter = {      
    _thematic: fullDocument.thematic ? format(fullDocument.thematic) : [],      
};
const docId = changeEvent.documentKey._id;

const collection = context.services.get("my-cluster").db("dev").collection("projects");

const doc = collection.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: docId },
    { $set: setter });

return;
};
```

I'm pretty sure it can be done in a cleaner way, so if someone post it, I'll switch the selected answer to her/his.

Another way to solve this is to make a custom analyser with character mapping that will replace each digit with its string counterpart. I haven’t tried this one tho. See https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/analyzers/custom/#mapping

Alternatives welcome!